# Issues updating record using mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to update/edit my user form, but when I click the "edit" button, I'm not getting the  expected results. It should display the new data, but It displays the old data instead.

coding:

```
<?php 

include"errorReporting.php";
 include "conn.php";
 $conn = connect();
 $conndb = connectdb();

$wardID = $_REQUEST["wardID"];
$RequestName = $_REQUEST["RequestName"];
$Department = $_REQUEST["Department"];
$Position = $_REQUEST["Position"];
$Date= $_REQUEST["Date"];
$TypeOfRequest = $_REQUEST["TypeOfRequest"];
$PleaseSpecify = $_REQUEST["PleaseSpecify"];
$DateRequire = $_REQUEST["DateRequire"];
$DateReturn = $_REQUEST["DateReturn"];

mysqli_select_db($conn,"misadmin") or die ($conn->error ."\n");
$query = "select * from requestform";
$result2= $conn->query($query) or die ($conn->error ."\n");
$row_result =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);

mysqli_select_db($conn,"misadmin") or die ($conn->error ."\n");
$conn ->query("UPDATE requestform SET RequestName='$RequestName',Department='$Department',Position='$Position',Date='$Date',TypeOfRequest='$TypeOfRequest',PleaseSpecify='$PleaseSpecify',DateRequire='$DateRequire',DateReturn='$DateReturn' where wardID='$wardID'",$conn->affected_rows);

$result_update=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);



header("Location:requestform3.php");
?>
```

output:
[image: this is edit page]

[image: update to new record]

[image: did not change anything]

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: Check your where statement. You are trying to update where wardID=new_value(med). At that moment wardId is equal to old_value (4f)

Comment: @LeaTano but if i want to edit the other data? did i need to declare new_value and the old_value first? if i had 40 data to update do  i need to declare it first?

Comment: If you have 40 records with different wardIDs and you want yo change all of them to 'x' you have to query: UPDATE requestform SET wardID='x' WHERE wardID IN(1,2,3,4,5...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had found my answer. after i redo back my coding using the old template

**here are the code.**

```
<?php 
// to connect with the database system
include "errorReporting.php";
 include "conn.php";
 $conn = connect();
 $conndb = connectdb();

 $wardID = $_REQUEST["wardID"];
 $RequestName = $_REQUEST["RequestName"];
 $Department = $_REQUEST["Department"];
$Position = $_REQUEST["Position"];
$DateRequest = $_REQUEST["DateRequest"];
$TypeOfRequest = $_REQUEST["TypeOfRequest"];
$PleaseSpecify = $_REQUEST["PleaseSpecify"];
$DateRequire = $_REQUEST["DateRequire"];
$DateReturn = $_REQUEST["DateReturn"]; 

mysqli_select_db($conn,"misadmin") or die (mysql_error()."\n");

$query = "select * from requestform" ;

$result = $conn->query($query) or die (mysql_error()."\n".$query);

$row_result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

mysqli_select_db($conn,"misadmin")or die (mysql_error(). "\n");
//to update the data 
$update="update requestform SET
RequestName='$RequestName' ,Department='$Department' ,Position='$Position' ,DateRequest='$DateRequest' ,TypeOfRequest='$TypeOfRequest',PleaseSpecify='$PleaseSpecify' ,DateRequire='$DateRequire' ,DateReturn='$DateReturn' where wardID='$wardID'";

$rowinsert=$conn->query($update);

header("Location:requestform3.php");
?>
```

thanks for those who gave the suggestions.I had learnt a lot from you all.

Answer (score 1):

in `where wardID='???'` Must retrieve the data before it changes. i mean "4f" not "med".

you can add a textbok in your post form :

```
<input type="hidden" id="original_wardID" value="<?php echo $wardID?>" />
```

in your php code add :

```
$ori_wardID=$_REQUEST['original_wardID'];
```

then change your sql :

```
UPDATE requestform SET wardID='$wardID',RequestName='$RequestName',Department='$Department',Position='$Position',Date='$Date',TypeOfRequest='$TypeOfRequest',PleaseSpecify='$PleaseSpecify',DateRequire='$DateRequire',DateReturn='$DateReturn' where wardID='$ori_wardID'
```

Comment: yeah thanks for the suggestion. always keep try and error

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
$conn ->query("UPDATE requestform SET RequestName='$RequestName',Department='$Department',Position='$Position',Date='$Date',TypeOfRequest='$TypeOfRequest',PleaseSpecify='$PleaseSpecify',DateRequire='$DateRequire',DateReturn='$DateReturn' where wardID=$wardID ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"UPDATE requestform SET RequestName='$RequestName',Department='$Department',Position='$Position',Date='$Date',TypeOfRequest='$TypeOfRequest',PleaseSpecify='$PleaseSpecify',DateRequire='$DateRequire',DateReturn='$DateReturn' where wardID='$wardID'"
```

change to

```
"UPDATE requestform SET RequestName='".$RequestName."',Department='".$Department."',Position='".$Position."',Date='".$Date."',TypeOfRequest='".$TypeOfRequest."',PleaseSpecify='".$PleaseSpecify."',DateRequire='".$DateRequire."',DateReturn='".$DateReturn."' where wardID=".$wardID
```

or like this demo code

```
$db_sql="select id ,uid,regdate from `newtable` where id=?";
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($db_sql);//
$stmt->bind_param("i",$id);// i int d double s string b blob
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

but I guess use pdo will be better

Comment: I don't know your var type,but string like this 'var',and int have no ''

Comment: And I think you use the bind var of mysqli can solve this problem,and it also
 can avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){//save database}` or if `(isset $_POST['edit']){//save database}` for the edit button in order to save data when edit button is clicked.

Plus you are using Date in your `UPDATE` query (Date =). `DATE` is also as a native function used in MYSQL, you need to change it. In case you changed it to DateChanged use prepared statement it helps your code to be more readable.

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' )
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE requestform  SET RequestName=?, 
    Department=?, Position=?, DateChanged=?, TypeOfRequest=?, 
    PleaseSpecify=?, DateRequire=?, DateReturn=? WHERE wardID=?");

    $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $RequestName, $Department, 
    $Position, $DateChanged, $TypeOfRequest, $PleaseSpecify, 
    $DateRequire, $wardID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();

}
```

Comment: add the erros that you are having. use try and catch to see the problem.